# Mi método de remoción provoca un comportamiento inesperado en mi colección

Tags: php, array, collection

En PHP 8.1, estoy escribiendo una colección que expone un iterador mediante la implementación de `\Iterator`, tal que:

```
interface CollectionIterator extends \Iterator
{
    function prev() : void;
}

class Collection implements CollectionIterator
{
    protected array $items;
    protected int   $position;

    public function __construct(array $items)
    {
        $this->items    = $items;
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function add(mixed $item) : void
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function remove(mixed $item) : void
    {
        $indice = array_search($item, $this->items);
    
        if ($indice !== false)
        {
            unset($this->items[$indice]);
        }
    }

    public function count() : int
    {
        return count($this->items);
    }

    public function at(int $index) : mixed
    {
        return $this->items[$index];
    }

    public function toArray() : array
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function clone() : Collection
    {
        return new Collection($this->items);
    }

// Implementación de `CollectionIterator`.

    public function next() : void
    {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    public function prev() : void
    {
        --$this->position;
    }

    public function current() : mixed
    {
        return $this->items[$this->position];
    }

    public function key() : int
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function rewind() : void
    {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function valid() : bool
    {
        return isset($this->items[$this->position]);
    }

// Fin de implementación de `CollectionIterator`.
}
```

Mi problema reside en la invocación a mi método `remove`. Al ser invocado, provoca el siguiente comportamiento inesperado:

```
$items = new Collection(['Pepe', 'Ana', 'Luis', 'Ronaldo']);
$items->remove('Ana');

// Solo imprime: "Pepe"
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}

// Funciona correctamente. Imprime: "Pepe", "Luis" y "Ronaldo"
foreach ($items->toArray() as $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}

// Imprime: "Pepe" y lanza un error de clave no definida en la posición 1 de mi arreglo
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->count(); $i++)
{
    $item = $items->at($i);
    var_dump($item);
}
```

---

Probé cambiando la implementación de `remove`:

```
public function remove(mixed $item) : void
{
    $itemsFlip = array_flip($this->items);

    if (isset($itemsFlip[$item]))
    {
        unset($this->items[ $itemsFlip[$item] ]);
    }
}
```

Pero obtuve el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que `unset()` no reindexa el array dentro del objeto `items` y queda el espacio.

Si haces `var_dump` después de `$items->remove('Ana');`, tendrás esto:

```php
object(Collection)#1 (2) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Pepe"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Luis"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Ronaldo"
  }
  ["position":protected]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Al recorrer la propiedad `'items'` con `foreach` no pasa nada, pero con un `for()` normal, al caer en el elemento `[1]`, este no existe.

Algunas formas de resolverlo:

- Usar `foreach()` en vez de `for()`
- Reindexar el array del objeto:

```php
    public function remove(mixed $item) : void 
    {
        $indice = array_search($item, $this->items);
        if ($indice !== false) 
        {
            unset($this->items[$indice]);
            $this->items = array_values($this->items); // <-- reindexación
        }
    }
```

**¿Por qué el primer `foreach` solo devuelve 'pepe'?**
Es por la misma razón del error de *clave no definida* del último `for`.
Debido a que el método `next()` incrementa `++$this->position;`, entonces cuando `$this->position == 1`, el método `current()` no podrá devolver nada y el iterador termina.

Ese problema también se arregla con la reindexación de `$this->items`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ignoraba el detalle de la reindexación.